# my threejs vanilla html code when implemented in react doesn't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

i had a fully working 3js code in vanilla HTML, i thought to use it in my react app, i did this for that

my component code

```
export default function MyThree() {
    return (
        <>
            <div id="out">
                <audio id="audio" src="./music-moonshine.mp3" controls></audio>
                <div id="out"></div>
            </div>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/84/three.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.6.3/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplex-noise/2.3.0/simplex-noise.min.js"></script>
            <script src="./script.js"></script>
        </>
    );
}
```

my script.js i copied and pasted in the same folder as my component and its code is this
https://codeshare.io/8p3Oev

Comment: you can't put your scripts inside your JSX like this. Instead you should either install them via `npm install` or add them to your `index.html` file (in `public` directory if you use CRA). As for your custom script, you can put it inside of a `useEffect` (with an empty dependency array), so that it will load when your component will be mounted.